# How to request scale up from 0 to X the number of nodes in a Nodepool in Azure Kubernetes using nodeSelector?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, autoscaling

I have a kubernetes cluster (v1.24.3) running in Azure with 3 nodepools called small, standard and large. For each of these nodepools I have added a label named `type`, where the value is `SMALL-2CPU-8GB`, `STANDARD-4CPU-16GB` and `LARGE-8CPU-32GB` respectively. These nodepools are also configured with the autoscaler from Azure, and the min is 0 and the max is 10.

Now, I am deploying my applications which are required to run in each of these nodepools depending on the specification - for example, one of the apps requires a small node, so it is requesting to run in the nodepool called `small` with a label `type=SMALL-2CPU-8GB` and so on.

The way I am requesting this is by setting the `nodeSelector` in the manifest of the application. Exactly this is the portion of the template:

```yaml
# App 1
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        nodeSelector:
          type: LARGE-8CPU-32GB
          agentpool: large
# App 2
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        nodeSelector:
          type: STANDARD-4CPU-16GB
          agentpool: standard

# App 3
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        nodeSelector:
          type: SMALL-4CPU-16GB
          agentpool: small
...
```

When I apply the manifest to the cluster, the pods are in pending state with the message:

```
Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp       43m (x13 over 45m)     cluster-autoscaler       pod didn't trigger scale-up: 3 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector, 1 not ready for scale-up
```

And I can see that the node count is still **0**, so the pod is not triggering the autoscaler to request a new node.

**My question is**, how to make the autoscaler work when I am requesting nodes (even when the nodepool has zero nodes) via the `nodeSelector`? Should I specify a different label or use taints?

Comment: Predefining instances based on size seems really odd as that somewhat bypasses k8s resource scheduling. Do your nodes also have a label named `agentpool`?

Comment: Fair enough, how is that bypassing the k8s resource scheduling? Yes the agentpool is a label assigned by azure to their nodes and correspond to the name of the nodepool. In fact, I could delete the `type` label as it is redundant but I wanted to keep it.